# Go-GRPC transport layer authentication

Tags: authentication, go, tcp, grpc, transport

I am trying to implement transport layer /client/ authentication, that is **not** based on certificates. The problem is that I am using ALB(Application Load Balancer) which, unfortunately, terminates the SSL connection, so certificates are not an option. What are some reliable alternatives? Did you have similar problem on your side?

Answer (score 0):

TLS is just one type of transport layer authentication. There are implementations for several other authentications mechanisms in the [google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/*](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials#section-directories) packages), both for the transport layer, and for per-call authentication (such as OAuth2).

If none of them suit your needs, you can write your own by implementing either [the TransportCredentials interface](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials#TransportCredentials) or [the PerRPCCredentials interface](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials#PerRPCCredentials).